Does 風の吹くに任せて、どこを見ても feel natural?
This short passage comes from chapter 24 of Kokoro and was the basis for a recent question by another member.

東京へ帰ってみると、松飾はいつか取り払われていた。町は寒い風の吹くに任せて、どこを見てもこれというほどの正月めいた景気はなかった。

I have a different question: Is there an implied but omitted phrase, like 散策していると, after 任せて? And if so, does the second sentence feel completely natural even with the phrase omitted? To me, if I follow the Japanese literally it seems as if the narrator is allowing his gaze, rather than his movements through the city streets, to be directed by the wind. But that doesn't seem very likely, or at least isn't something an English speaker would be likely to say.
Also: If you did insert a phrase like 散策してると after 任せて, would you also have to change 町は to 町を, or change the phrasing in some other way?

This is about a usage of the verb 任せる.

３ そのままにしておく。ほうっておく。「髪の毛が乱れるに—・せる」「成り行きに—・せる」（ https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%BB%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B/ ）

So 町 plays a role of the subject of 任せる and it was "letting cold winds blow".
